# How to create a Non-Freezing Infinite Loop?

Tags: c++, windows, time, infinite-loop

My question is as follows:

How to create an infinite loop in C++ which doesn't freeze the window, keeps it responsive and allows for program to be closed at any time?

Example:

```
#include <Windows.h>
int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        FlashPrettyGraphics();
        Sleep(10);
    }
}
```

This program, as it is right now, will work for approx. a dozen seconds, after which it will become unresponsive and crash. During the execution the window will be unable to be moved.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Search for **thread**

Comment: Search for **event handling**. Your window freezes and executable crashes because you don't handle events that your window receives. It does not matter if your loop is infinite or not, the only requirement to handle events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is generally accomplished with multi-threading.  You create one thread that interacts with the user and then you create another thread that has the infinite loop that does the processing.

Comment: Right how OP misses event handling, that's why his window freezes and executable crashes (because of event queue overflow). What he asks for can be easily achieved with one or multiple threads, the only requirement is to handle events quickly. Now **OP shall add proper event handling, without it a new thread will change nothing**.